# Resource Does Not exist in Namespace xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got a problem. My project can't find the 'Resource' class in the namespace. I have done the following things:

- Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Deleted the Bin and Obj folders
- Deleted and Generated the Resource.Designer
- Checked the Namespace of the Resource.Designer(and it's the same)

[The namespace in the resource designer is the same with the rest of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akpJw.png)

What's else can I do? I have been stuck there for quite a while. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post the exact error messages you are seeing.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Resource' does not exist in the namespace 'PlanNaira.Droid' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: The screenshot of the error: https://photos.app.goo.gl/cHit7g7NspVUcDLz9

Comment: I have even updated my xamarin, what else can I try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall the following:
-Xamarin
-Xamarin for Windows
-Xamarin.Android
-Xamarin.iOS
-Xamarin for Visual Studio,
   and install an older version of Xamarin.